# QTP 11: Load Environment Variable using AOM

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to set environment variable using AOM

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\"
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
If qtApp.Launched <> True Then
    With qtApp
        .Launch
        .Visible = True
        .Options.Run.RunMode = "Fast"
        .Options.Run.ViewResults = False
        .Open "C:\_Work\MAIN\TestDriver", False

        Set qtTest = .Test
        With qtTest
            .Settings.Run.OnError = "NextStep"
            .Settings.Resources.Libraries.RemoveAll
            .Environment.LoadFromFile "C:\_Work\MAIN\Configuration\Test2.xml"
            .Run
        End With
    End With
End If
```

In the QTP script, I am using user defined environment variables (as defined in Test2.xml) but it doesn't work because the file wasn't loaded. I checked the settings too and there are no user defined EVs.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it is a bug from UFT or may be we are missing something, but **`Environment.LoadFromFile`** from .vbs file is NOT working.

As of now the workaround would be loading the Environment variable file in your UFT test script - **`TestDriver`**.

Put this code at the top of your code.

```
'Check if an External Environment file is loaded and if not, load it.
Dim fileName
fileName = Environment.ExternalFileName
If (fileName = "") Then
    Environment.LoadFromFile("C:\_Work\MAIN\Configuration\Test2.xml")
End If
Msgbox Environment.Value("Your_Variable_Name")
...
'your rest of the code
```

If you don't want to go to this route, than you might need to contact HP.

Comment: That's what I thought. Something is not right with `Environment.LoadFromFile` via AOM. Although your workaround is good but it won't suit my needs. I need to specify different EV files based on the environment (which I would be setting in the outside VBS file). So there has to be a way where the QTP script can understand which environment it is dealing with at the beginning

Comment: Make sense. So how you run your script every time? Using VBScript?

Comment: Yes. Before running QTP, I have to do some setup which I take care of using a mix of VBS and BAT files. Was trying to make the environment variables dynamic (before start of test) ... but now I think I will have to do dirty workaround

Comment: Then in that case, assign Input parameter to your UFT script and pass the parameter from your VbScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim App 'As Application
Set App = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
App.Launch
App.Visible = True
App.Open "C:\Automation\OracleEBS", False
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Java").Active = False
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Java").CommandLine = ""
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Java").WorkingDirectory = ""
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Oracle").Active = False
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Oracle").Address = ""
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Oracle").AutoLogin = False
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Oracle").User = ""
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Oracle").Password = ""
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Oracle").LogoutOnExit = False
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Oracle").CloseOnExit = False
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Web").Active = True
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Web").Browser = "CHROME"
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Web").Address = "http://newtours.demoaut.com "
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Web").CloseOnExit = True
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Windows Applications").Active = True
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Windows Applications").Applications.RemoveAll
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Windows Applications").RecordOnQTDescendants = True
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Windows Applications").RecordOnExplorerDescendants = True
App.Test.Settings.Launchers("Windows Applications").RecordOnSpecifiedApplications = True
App.Test.Settings.Run.IterationMode = "rngAll"
App.Test.Settings.Run.StartIteration = 1
App.Test.Settings.Run.EndIteration = 1
App.Test.Settings.Run.ObjectSyncTimeOut = 20000
App.Test.Settings.Run.DisableSmartIdentification = False
App.Test.Settings.Run.OnError = "Dialog"
App.Test.Settings.Resources.DataTablePath = "<Default>"
App.Test.Settings.Resources.Libraries.RemoveAll
App.Test.Settings.Resources.Libraries.Add("C:\UFTAutomation\function_Libraray\FL.txt")
App.Test.Environment.LoadFromFile "C:\Users\uftuser01\Desktop\env.xml"
App.Test.Settings.Web.BrowserNavigationTimeout = 60000
App.Test.Settings.Web.ActiveScreenAccess.UserName = ""
App.Test.Settings.Web.ActiveScreenAccess.Password = ""
App.Test.Settings.Recovery.Enabled = True
App.Test.Settings.Recovery.SetActivationMode "OnError"
App.Test.Settings.Recovery.Add "C:\tmp\FRecovery.qrs", "First Recovery Scenario", 1
App.Test.Settings.Recovery.Item(1).Enabled = True 
App.Test.Settings.Java.EditSet.KeyPressed = True
App.Test.Settings.Java.EditSet.KeyTyped = True
App.Test.Settings.Java.EditSet.KeyReleased = True
App.Test.Settings.Java.EditSet.InputMethod = False
App.Test.Settings.Java.EditSet.FocusLost = False
App.Test.Settings.Java.EditSet.JavaAPI = False
App.Test.Settings.Java.EditSet.JavaAPICharactersToExclude = "\t\n\r"
App.Test.Settings.Java.DeviceReplay.Click = False
App.Test.Settings.Java.DeviceReplay.DoubleClick = False
App.Test.Settings.Java.DeviceReplay.Type = False
App.Test.Settings.Java.DeviceReplay.DragDrop = False
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' System Local Monitoring settings
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
App.Test.Settings.LocalSystemMonitor.Enable = false
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Log Tracking settings
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
With App.Test.Settings.LogTracking 
    .IncludeInResults = False 
    .Port = 18081 
    .IP = "127.0.0.1" 
    .MinTriggerLevel = "ERROR" 
    .EnableAutoConfig = False 
    .RecoverConfigAfterRun = False 
    .ConfigFile = "" 
    .MinConfigLevel = "WARN" 
End With
```

Comment: How do I attach it to the test? For example, C:\_Work\MAIN\TestDriver

Comment: OK. The current updated answer is just setting it up (I also got similar script using QTP's generate script). But the problem is that i am unable to attach the env file to the said test (in which i am trying to use the env vars)

Comment: Line5 & 34 will do the trick.  5 - Opens the given test, 34 attached the environment.xml

Comment: I don't know how your solution is any different than what I have tried. In your solution, the test is not even run. The file is attached to the test but the problem still persists. QTP refuses to identify the external variables which was my original issue.

Comment: The above code worked fine for me. I could verify the user-defined environment variables loaded successfully under Settings->Environment->User Defined. Would you mind posting your xml file?

Comment: I am on QTP 11..Which version you are testing it on? The file works because when used in the test, it shows all the vars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135282/discussion-between-barney-and-pankaj-jaju).